# How to use Mysql variables with Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, variables, conflict

I need to use a native sql query in Hibernate with use of variable.

But hibernate throws an error saying: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix

So there is a conflict with the := mysql variable assignment and hibernate variable assignment.

Here is my sql query:

```
SET @rank:=0; 
UPDATE Rank SET rank_Level=@rank:=@rank+1 ORDER BY Level;
```

the hibernate code (jpa syntax):

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(theQuery);
query.executeUpdate();
```

I can't use a stored procedure because my sql query is dynamically generated ('Level' can be 'int' or 'force'...)

How can I do this ?

thanks

Comment: Please add the Hibernate code.

Comment: I've just added it but this is a very simple common case

Comment: You are not alone,
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=992931&start=0
http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2697
Maybe have one stored procedure per order by clause.

Comment: Yes I found these two links before posting (it is for that I'm saying that I can't use stored procedure)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I finally use stored procedure (yes, what I don't want initially) to create dynamic query (I don't think it was possible).

Here is my code:
The stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER |

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS UpdateRank |

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRank(IN shortcut varchar(30))
BEGIN
    SET @rank=0;
    SET @query=CONCAT('UPDATE Rank SET ', shortcut, '=@rank:=@rank+1 ORDER BY ', shortcut);     

    PREPARE q1 FROM @query;
    EXECUTE q1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE q1;
END;

|
DELIMITER ;
```

The tip is the use of the CONCAT function to dynamically create a query in the stored procedure.

Then, call the procedure in classic hibernate function:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("CALL updateRank('lvl')");
q.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Make sure to prevent sql injection.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I've already protect it (my shortcut is only letters)

Comment: I found better approach to this issue with Hibernate Interceptor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460018/how-can-i-use-mysql-assign-operator-in-hibernate-native-query. I think using stored procedure is awful idea if there's alternative.

Comment: Yes you are right, it seems to be a better approach ! Thanks for notifying that.

Answer (score 3):

I'll copy paste my answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/25552002/3987202
Another solution for those of us who can't make the jump to Hibernate 4.1.3.
Simply use `/*'*/:=/*'*/` inside the query. Hibernate code treats everything between `'` as a string (ignores it). MySQL on the other hand will ignore everything inside a blockquote and will evaluate the whole expression to an assignement operator.
I know it's quick and dirty, but it get's the job done without stored procedures, interceptors etc.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [MySQL Proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/proxy-gettingstarted.html) to rewrite the query after Hibernate has sent the query to the database.

For example supply Hibernate with this,

```
UPDATE Rank SET rank_Level=incr(@rank) ORDER BY Level;
```

but rewrite it to this,

```
UPDATE Rank SET rank_Level=@rank:=@rank+1 ORDER BY Level;
```

Comment: HOW STUPID IS HIBERNATE HUH?