# How can I use MySQL assign operator(:=) in hibernate native query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, nativequery

I'm using Hibernate. I wrote some native query because I need to use sub select statement.

Query looks like this:

```
SELECT sub.rownum FROM 
    (SELECT k.`news_master_id` AS id, @row := @row + 1 AS rownum 
        FROM keyword_news_list k 
        JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) r 
        WHERE k.`keyword_news_id` = :kid
    ORDER BY k.`news_master_id` ASC) AS sub 
WHERE sub.id  = :nid
```

When I run this query like this:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createSQLQuery(query)
    .setParameter("kid", kid)
    .setParameter("nid", nid)
    .uniqueResult();
```

This exception comes out:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' ....
```

This might because of `:=` operator. I found some [Hibernate issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2697) about this. This issue is still open. Isn't there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Is there any thing that can help you from here? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value

Comment: @ManuPK Thanks, but it didn't help. I think there's no solution for my question. I found similar question with mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2712240/how-to-use-mysql-variables-with-hibernate but there's no good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can implement this is a slightly different way.. you need to replace the : operator with something else (say '|' char )  and in your interceptor replace the '|' with the : .

this way hibernate will not try to think the : is a param but will ignore it

For the interceptor logic you can refer to the [hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html)

This has worked for me using MySQL 5.

remember, this replacing of : must be only done to ':=' and other MySQL specific requirments.. don't try to replace the : for the param-placeholders. (hibernate will not be able to identify the params then)

Comment: HOW STUPID IS HIBERNATE HUH? I can imagine the coder going. Nah, how could there EVER be a colon in the SQL. No chance! Let's make it so there is no escaping mechanism!

Comment: Sorry, was a bit pissed of about having to work around. The solution above is only if you only have a hammer. You can also use \: to escape the colons, though in my case, it broke every single named parameter (they just stopped working.)

Answer (score 32):

Note that [HHH-2697](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2697?attachmentOrder=asc&oldIssueView=true) is now fixed for Hibernate 4.1.3 You can now escape with backslash:

```
SELECT k.`news_master_id` AS id, @row \:= @row + 1 AS rownum 
    FROM keyword_news_list k 
    JOIN (SELECT @row \:= 0) r 
    WHERE k.`keyword_news_id` = :kid
ORDER BY k.`news_master_id` ASC
```

Comment: using **Hibernate 4.3.7 only one backslash is enough**, e.g. PG 9.3 query `select f( p_tst \:= 1 )`  (where it may be two in Java strings to escape them)

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, its effective and much more easy.

Comment: Works fine, in spring jpa repository for `@Query( value = "<...>" , nativeQuery = true)` , I had to use double backslash `\\:=` inside quotes to avoid compile time error.

Answer (score 19):

Another solution for those of us who can't make the jump to Hibernate 4.1.3.
Simply use `/*'*/:=/*'*/` inside the query. Hibernate code treats everything between `'` as a string (ignores it). MySQL on the other hand will ignore everything inside a blockquote and will evaluate the whole expression to an assignement operator.
I know it's quick and dirty, but it get's the job done without stored procedures, interceptors etc.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to include Spring JDBC and execute the query rather than fight against Hibernate interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

in [Hibernate exception on encountering mysql := operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146012/hibernate-exception-on-encountering-mysql-operator) **Stanislav** gave another option other than interceptor to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your SQL-files away from Java code - try this piece of code. Played a lot to get the right number of escaping slashes:

```
String sqlPattern = FileUtils.readFile(this.getClass(), /sql/my_query.sql");
sqlPattern = sqlPattern.replaceAll(":=", "\\\\:=");
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlPattern);
```

Answer (score -6):

I guess there should not be a space after = , the operator should be written as =: (without any spaces)