# In a custom dialect, how can I get Hibernate to ignore colons

Tags: hibernate

I have the following custom dialect functions:

```
     registerFunction("weight_running_total",
       new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.STRING, "(@runtot := @runtot + weight)"))

    // This one takes an argument and saves it off in a variable named @val, that can be retrieved later in the same connection
    registerFunction("save_off_last_value",
        new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.STRING, "@val := ?1"))
```

But instead of just passing through, Hibernate is complaining about the colons, and giving me the 'Invalid filter-parameter name format' exception.  I've found others with this issue, but haven't seen the solution, so asking for help here...

BTW, this is Hibernate 3 (can't currently upgrade), b/c I'm using Grails.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a super-big hack... if it doesn't work out for someone else, you could always fall back to the idea of changing the query in a Hibernate filter somehow (see [How can I use MySQL assign operator(:=) in hibernate native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460018/how-can-i-use-mysql-assign-operator-in-hibernate-native-query)), but I didn't dig deeply on how to implement that in GORM.

Hibernate will not ignore the ':' no matter what you do - it looks for that character specifically.  After looking at the Hibernate code for QueryParameters, if session.getEnabledFilters().size()==0, it will take a code path that will not break (in my case, I noticed my query that is just slightly different than this one was taking that code path anyway).  There is only one filter enabled, the dynamicFilterEnabler.  So I do this just before my query:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().disableFilter('dynamicFilterEnabler')
```

then turn it back on after this query.

I had no idea what that filter was, so I did some searching and found some info about it in several JIRA tickets:

- http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6807
- http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6681
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2624

apparently it is a workaround required when you use the same domain object in both a hasMany and a belongsTo.  I don't have this situation, so I'm able to turn it off (for now).  Ugly, but it works for now.