# Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

My problem is i try to insert text that contain char : in my query

I have tried to put double backslash // before char : but still not working.

```
ABNORMALLY.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' 

INSERT INTO TABLE_A  (A_ID, TYPE_ID, F_ID, REFNO, RECORD) VALUES 
( A_ID_SEQ.nextval, 4 , 9 , 'NY167', q'[LA2010167|SNIP' N CLIP|LMG|1.Unit no\\: 1046, 1 st Floor, Limbang Plaza, 98700 Limbang|2010-12-10||]')
```

Comment: enclosing the query in single-quotes seems wrong. what context is this appearing in?

Comment: Similar question was answered  here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9461939/4454454

Comment: @NathanHughes i just update the info. there is no single quote for enclosing the query. this is when i put the query in log.info()

Comment: @MaxZoom using interceptor in one way, but i really dont know how to code it. i prefer other faster way, which something like put additional double backslash to make it worked.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to add the values as parameters instead of hard-coding them? that way they would be out of the way at the time that hibernate parses this looking for named parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here Hibernate is parsing an insert that contains a hard-coded value that has a colon in it. If you rewrite the insert to use parameters then Hibernate won't see the value as part of the statement.

Answer (score 17):

From my experience I will tell you. There are two scenarios 

1) You want to specify a parameter in the query whose value set dynamically.

```
eg: where user_id = :userId
```

Here you wont get any problem if you are setting parameter with same name as "userId";

2) You are typecasting the value

```
eg: select count(id) :: integer
```

when you are doing this you have to use escape character otherwise hibernate will think that it is a parameter. And it will give an error **"All parameters are not set "**
you can overcome this with writing code using escape character

```
eg:select count(id) \\:\\: integer
```

So this will solve your problem.
And if you are wrongly used forward slash instead of backward slash you will get the error **"space is not allowed after prefix"**

```
Wrong: select count(id)//://: integer
Right: select count(id)\\:\\: integer
```

But I highly recommended you to use the CAST function instead of using `"::"` this operator
ie `select CAST(count(id) as integer)`
It is the better way of type casting and it will lead to minimal errors

Comment: i had the problem with assignment in mysql: @current_client_user_id := client_user_id

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve this problem via Spring Boot and I have created a function (actually a procedure) and used it as a query and the problem has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your RECORD column contains ":", so, Hibernate waits for a parameter after it.
I hade the same problem of you

Comment: so help this person with a solution