# how to resolve the sql query in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

```
SELECT
          first_name,
          age,
          gender,
          @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
FROM
          person p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
ORDER BY  age;
```

when am executing this query through hibernate am getting an error

> "Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'"

how to resolve

Comment: am using hibernate 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423741/space-is-not-allowed-after-parameter-prefix)

Comment: I removed space after ':' then also am facing same issue.  Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'

Comment: can you edit the question with changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `:=` hibernate expects the parameter but you are passing 0.

Option 1 : remove `:=` and use 0 directly

```
SELECT @curRank = 0
```

Option 2 : pass value by parameter instead of 0

```
SELECT @curRank := someparameter
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it's not working. rank data is not coming. it's coming as null value in sql and hibernate also