# org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, native-sql

I'm trying to execute query , but got 
     Resolved exception caused by handler execution:   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' .
I done as advised here 
[How can I use MySQL assign operator(:=) in hibernate native query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460018/how-can-i-use-mysql-assign-operator-in-hibernate-native-query/9461939#9461939)
and here :
[Hibernate exception on encountering mysql := operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33146012/hibernate-exception-on-encountering-mysql-operator/) But same. 
hibernate version 5.2.17.Final

ClientRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<Client, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Client> {
@Query( value = "select * from client where center_id in\n" +
    "(select  id  from    (select * from center  order by parent_center_id, id) center_sorted,  (select @pv=:centerId) initialisation\n" +
    "where   find_in_set(parent_center_id, @pv) and  length(@pv:=concat(@pv, ',', id))) or center_id=:centerId;" ,nativeQuery = true)

Page<Client> findAllByCenterId(@Param("centerId") Long centerId, Pageable pageable) ;
```

}

Comment: To be honest you have a mixture of the parameters and raw fields. Could you separate the query at first and clean up the whole statement? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Formerly, when using the assignment operator in Native Query, Hibernate threw an exception.Hibernate supports escaping the colon char not to treat it as a parameter.
So, **You need to *escape with a backslash*.** : "**\\:=**"

Note that no spaces are allowed before and after the reference placeholder.

Comment: I did :   

    @Query( value = "select * from client where center_id in\n" +
        "(select  id  from    (select * from center  order by parent_center_id, id) center_sorted,  (select @pv = :centerId) initialisation\n" +
        "where   find_in_set(parent_center_id, @pv) and  length(@pv\:= concat(@pv, ',', id))) or center_id = :centerId;" ,nativeQuery = true)

and now i got :

 Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/src/main/java/com/mycompany/hiptest/repository/ClientRepository.java:[24,69] illegal escape character

Comment: I try more easy  query  :
 @Query( value = "select * from client where center_id = :centerId " ,nativeQuery = true)

It's  worked.

Comment: No. You should escape "\:=" in final SQL string passed to Hibernate and if script is dynamically prepared in Java code - with four slashes in `mySqlString.replaceAll(":=", "\\\\:=")`. Double escaping - for Hibernate and for Java.