# Hibernate escaping ":" character

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I've found some posts here and some answers. I've tried every each of them with bad results. I don't want to use stored procedures.

I'm using Hibernate in Java, with MySQL. Some of my query string is:

```
SET @rank = 0; 
SET @limit = 0.1; 
SELECT (@limit := ROUND(COUNT(id) * @limit)) FROM Pics;
SELECT Q1.popularity FROM Pics AS p INNER JOIN (
   SELECT IF((@rank := @rank + 1) <= @limit, true, false) AS 'popularity', p.id 
   FROM Pics AS p 
   ORDER BY p.points DESC
) AS Q1 ON Q1.id = p.id WHERE p.id = 7;
```

Some people said a solution is using `/*'*/:=/*'*/` inside the query ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9460018/how-can-i-use-mysql-assign-operator-in-hibernate-native-query/25552002#25552002)), but it doesn't work for me:

```
SET @rank = 0; 
SET @limit = 0.1; 
SELECT (@limit /*'*/:=/*'*/ ROUND(COUNT(id) * @limit)) FROM Pics;
SELECT Q1.popularity FROM Pics AS p INNER JOIN (
   SELECT IF((@rank /*'*/:=/*'*/ @rank + 1) <= @limit, true, false) AS 'popularity', p.id 
   FROM Pics AS p 
   ORDER BY p.points DESC
) AS Q1 ON Q1.id = p.id WHERE p.id = 7;
```

I'm despereted!

Any idea, please? I'd be so grateful!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the logic behind your query?

Comment: Don't think about that, is just a example. It's not the full query, only pieces of code with the ":=" characters.

Comment: Well I'm thinking about it.  In particular, I'm thinking you should avoid using session variables with Hibernate, and maybe I can give you a workaround.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit the query and put the original example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could fix it using double backslash inside the Java query code:

```
SET @rank = 0; 
SET @limit = 0.1; 
SELECT (@limit \\:= ROUND(COUNT(id) * @limit)) FROM Pics;
SELECT Q1.popularity FROM Pics AS p INNER JOIN (
   SELECT IF((@rank \\:= @rank + 1) <= @limit, true, false) AS 'popularity', p.id 
   FROM Pics AS p 
   ORDER BY p.points DESC
) AS Q1 ON Q1.id = p.id WHERE p.id = 7;
```